# Image deload itself in a filtered list

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, caching

I have a filtered image list with buttons to change the filter in which changes the rendered list.

The problem is that after back and forth switching sometimes images get deloaded and needs to be downloaded again.

I tried using v-once and still doesn't fix the issue

[Codepen](https://s.codepen.io/villagelukaschen/debug/MdbQmK/mWkoNxJaZawA)

```html
<button v-on:click="filter('all')">All</button>
  <button v-on:click="filter('tag1')">Tag 1</button>
  <button v-on:click="filter('tag2')">Tag 2</button>

  <div class="list-complete"      tag="section">
    <div
      v-for="item in filteredItems"
      v-bind:key="item.id"
      class="list-complete-item"
    >
      <img class="list-complete-img" :src="item.img" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

```
methods: {
  filter(tag) {
    this.currentTag= tag;
  }
},
computed: {
  filteredItems: function() {
    var filter = this.currentTag;
    return this.items.filter(function(item) {
        return item.tags.indexOf(filter) !== -1;
    });
  }
}
```

For some reason this issue is very hard to trigger in the codepen example(it deloads only sometime), but on my local dev environment the images deload every time I toggle the filters.

The Vue computed filters would remove the images directly from the Dom, I'm thinking would it be possible to let it just be display none like v-show?

Comment: Could it be due to dynamic images being fetched? I mean, have you tried using images with static urls such as `https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557263413-6571da794a5b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=800&h=630&fit=crop&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjF9`, instead of `https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x646`

Comment: Well this would make sense but on my local environment it is completely static and the images would still deload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you re-render the `img` elements on filtering, thus the images are fetched again.

I've removed the computed property and instead rendered the full list. To filter, I've used `v-show` on `.list-complete-item` to toggle visibility.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#list-complete-demo',
  data: {
    items: [{
        id: 1,
        tags: ['all', 'tag1'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x600'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x601'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x602'
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        tags: ['all', 'tag1'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x603'
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        tags: ['all', 'tag1'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x604'
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x605'
      },
      {
        id: 7,
        tags: ['all', 'tag1'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x606'
      },
      {
        id: 8,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x607'
      },
      {
        id: 9,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x608'
      },
      {
        id: 10,
        tags: ['all', 'tag1'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x608'
      },
      {
        id: 11,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x609'
      },
      {
        id: 12,
        tags: ['all', 'tag1'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x610'
      },
      {
        id: 13,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x611'
      },
      {
        id: 14,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x612'
      },
      {
        id: 15,
        tags: ['all', 'tag1'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x613'
      },
      {
        id: 16,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x614'
      },
      {
        id: 17,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x615'
      },
      {
        id: 18,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x616'
      },
      {
        id: 19,
        tags: ['all', 'tag1'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x617'
      },
      {
        id: 20,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x618'
      },
      {
        id: 21,
        tags: ['all', 'tag1'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x619'
      },
      {
        id: 22,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x620'
      },
      {
        id: 23,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x621'
      },
      {
        id: 24,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x622'
      },
      {
        id: 25,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x623'
      },
      {
        id: 26,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x624'
      },
      {
        id: 27,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x625'
      },
      {
        id: 28,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x626'
      },
      {
        id: 29,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x627'
      },
      {
        id: 30,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x628'
      },
      {
        id: 31,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x629'
      },
      {
        id: 32,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x630'
      },
      {
        id: 33,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://sour3ce.unsplash.com/random/800x631'
      },
      {
        id: 34,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x632'
      },
      {
        id: 35,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x633'
      },
      {
        id: 36,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://sour46e.unsplash.com/random/800x634'
      },
      {
        id: 37,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x635'
      },
      {
        id: 38,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x636'
      },
      {
        id: 39,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x637'
      },
      {
        id: 40,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x638'
      },
      {
        id: 41,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x639'
      },
      {
        id: 42,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x640'
      },
      {
        id: 43,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x641'
      },
      {
        id: 44,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x642'
      },
      {
        id: 45,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x643'
      },
      {
        id: 46,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x644'
      },
      {
        id: 47,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x645'
      },
      {
        id: 48,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x646'
      },
      {
        id: 49,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x647'
      },
      {
        id: 50,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x648'
      },
      {
        id: 51,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x649'
      },
      {
        id: 52,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x650'
      },
      {
        id: 53,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x651'
      },
      {
        id: 54,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x652'
      },
      {
        id: 55,
        tags: ['all', 'tag2'],
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x653'
      }

    ],
    currentTag: 'all'
  },
  methods: {
    shuffle: function() {
      this.items = _.shuffle(this.items)
    },
    filter: function(tag) {
      this.currentTag = tag;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.list-complete {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.list-complete-item {
  transition: transform 1s;
  flex: 1 1 25%;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  /*   display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px; */
}

.list-complete-img {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.list-complete-enter,
.list-complete-leave-to
/* .list-complete-leave-active for <2.1.8 */

{
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(30px);
}

.list-complete-leave-active {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.1.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.14.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
<div id="list-complete-demo" class="demo">
  <button v-on:click="shuffle">Shuffle</button> Filter:
  <button v-on:click="filter('all')">All</button>
  <button v-on:click="filter('tag1')">Tag 1</button>
  <button v-on:click="filter('tag2')">Tag 2</button>

  <div class="list-complete" tag="section">
    <template v-for="item in items">
    <div
      v-bind:key="item.id"
      class="list-complete-item"
      v-show="item.tags.includes(currentTag)"
    >
      <img class="list-complete-img" :src="item.img" alt="" />
  </div>
  </template>
  </div>
```

Comment: but isn't it kind of a huge no no to use v-if or v-show on the same element as v-for?

Comment: Yea probably. You can move the loop to a template element.

Comment: But then you just come around with a lot of empty divs

Comment: Thanks! However I am wondering how to put the `v-show` sorting logic into the js as I need to pass in parameters but `computed` doesn't support parameters.

Comment: That's totally possible, right? You can create a method `filterItem` which returns the filtered array.

Comment: Ah yes I forgot about using methods for this, thanks!